# "Cannot resolve symbol'android:layout_width'"

Tags: android, android-styles

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for a category of vocabulary words -->
<style name="CategoryStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimens/list_item_height</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceMedium</item>
</style>
```

the above one is the `styles.xml` file.
and from the line 6 to 12 it shows"`Cannot resolve symbol'android:layout_width'`"
..............I want to know what the problem is???

Comment: Try changing the `layout_width` by giving it a dimesion if the error goes then it might be that `match_parent` is not allowed there because the parent is not yet known

Comment: no..the problem still persists.........does it have anything to do with manifest.xml?? i am a newbie at android...so my question might sound dumb....

Comment: No worry out. But its not necessary to define your full style in styles.xml if you are going to use it in one view only! Go to that view and change directly!

Answer (score 0):

Usually an error like this means its a syntax issue, but your code looks fine. Do you have this code nested inside of a resources tag? Because if you don't then that might be the issue.

Comment: I put the code in my styles.xml and there's no error. Take a look at who's calling "CategoryStyle" the problem must be there.